# Changes to <meta> tag generates asp.net error

Tags: asp.net, parsing, metadata

Greetings,

I have a bit of code on one of my pages (note, I'm not the original developer nor an asp.net programmer) that looks like this:

```
<meta id="metaDescription" runat="server" name="description" content="SEE CODE BEHIND" />
<meta id="metaKeywords" runat="server" name="keywords" content="SEE CODE BEHIND" />
```

The placement of the "id" element is interfering with sites that scrape the meta data resulting in it not being located on the page, so what I want to do is more the "name" element directly after `<meta>` and before the "id" element, but when I do that, I get an error:

Parser Error Message: The server tag is not well formed.

But what the heck do I need to do to fix this issue so I can get it the way I want it?

Answer (score 0):

Meta tags doesn't need the

```
runat="server"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<meta id="metaDescription" name="description" content="" runat="server" />
<meta id="metaKeywords" name="keywords" content="" runat="server" />
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. You answered a fairly old question. Please expand your answer to include an explanation. Since you are not likely to get any feedback from the OP, it is even more significant, as it may help others struggling with similar issues.